# Laravel model relationship across packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to refactor my project from having all code under the App folder into seperate composer packages. However I've hit a blocker which I could use some input to solve:

To simplify I'd like to create 2 packages, `Core` and `Customers`. I want `Core` to be fully seperated, having no references to any of my other packages. Inside `Core` there is a model called `Business`, and in `Customer` there is a model called `Customer`. There is a many-to-one relation ship between the models. The problem arises when I want to create the Eloquent relationship methods. `Customer` is dependant on `Core`, so this is not an issue, `$this->belongsTo(Business::class)`. However, to get the inverse `Core` needs to know about the `Customer` model, `$this->hasMany(Customer::class)`.

Is there a way around this? Like maybe registering a method on the `Business` model from my `Customer` package? Or have I gotten it all backwards?

**EDIT**

For those not familiar with Laravel, a relationship is defined as a function in the model class

```
class Business extends Model {
   public function customers() {
       return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't use laravel, but just from a PHP standpoint `$this->hasMany(Customer::class)` is the same as `$this->hasMany($someclass)` where `$someclass = Customer::class`.  Therefor you may be able to supply the class name as a variable when constructing `Core` and thereby break the dependency by injecting it instead (if that makes sense) assuming this is all run-time configuration stuff.

Comment: Yeah, that is one way to solve it. However I left out the surrounding function in my question (which was dumb...). The `$this->hasMany(Customer::class)` will be placed in a function called for example `customers()`. This means I have to create a function implying that there exists a relationship.

I could create a magic function for every "external" relationship. But I'm not a big fan of those...

Answer (score 0):

How most people do this is dependency injection, but that's more of a service type thing and less of a model relationship type thing. As you have it now I can think of a couple options.

1. Move the Business class out of core or customers into core. This depends on just how "core" these models are to your applications.
2. Dependency inject your relationship using an enum or registry

   ```
      class Business extends Model {
          public function customers() {
              return $this->hasMany(ModelEnum::byName('Customers')->class());
          }
      }
   ```

or

```
 class Business extends Model {
       public function customers() {
           $models = collect(get_declared_classes())->filter(function ($item) {
               $item == 'YOURPACKAGENAME\Models\\Customers' ? $item : throw new Exception();

               return $item
           });

           return $this->hasMany($item);
       }
    }
```

I think the best thing though would be to either add or remove the class(es), Having an intra package model kinda defeats the purpose of seperating you code with packages.

Comment: I'd like to avoid adding the function `customers` at all. What I'd like is for the `Core` package to not know about the existance of anything related to `Customer`

Comment: Then it sounds like your best bet is excluding business from core. Unless you 're comfortable with doing some more hacky stuff with [php runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's in `Core` or some other package. If I place `Business` in a `Business` package instead I still get a circular dependency, but now between `Business` and `Customer` packages instead.

Comment: So it seems like you want a non dependant dependency, which is impossible. Like I said in my comment, you can use your other package to monkey patch at runtime with the php runkit, but you're never going to get the connected functionality without having it defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. Just declare relation directly and throw exception if class does not exist:

   ```
   public function customers() {
       if (class_exists(Customer::class)) {
           throw new \SomeException();
       }

       return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
   }
   ```

   `::class` does not trigger autoloading, so it could be used even if class is not available. This will still create dependency on `Customers`, but at least it will be optional.
2. `Customers` package could provide `Business` with proper relation. So if you want to use `Business` class with `Customers`, you should use `Customers\Models\Business` instead of `Core\Models\Business`:

   ```
   class Business extends \Core\Models\Business {

       public function customers() {
           return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
       }
   }
   ```

   This will keep `Core` free from dependency on `Customers`, but it does not scale at all (you can't have second package which will do the same with `Business` class).